# What is responsible for soft rot of organic matter?

Tags: decomposition

In soft foods, for example, why is there a limited amount of time before consumption is no longer safe due to soft rotting of material.

Comment: Are you asking about why food becomes dangerous to eat or about why food becomes softer? They are related but some food softens without becoming dangerous or becomes dangerous without softening.

Comment: Both. Why some foods become dangerous to eat and also what makes the food become soft? Is it the decay of the organic matter inside the apple or is it a breakdown of the structural proteins on the surface?